# Get a generic type from JSON in WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to create a Web Api method that will accept JSON and a string with they name of the Type.

So far I have something like this:

```
public void Write(string typeName, string jsonData)
{
    var myType = Type.GetType(typeName);
    var fromJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutgoingEnvelope<myType>>(jsonData);
}
```

OutgoingEnvelope would be defined as this:

```
public class OutgoingEnvelope<T>
{
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    public OutgoingEnvelope()
    {
        Documents = new List<T>();
    }

    public List<T> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I'm getting the message:

> 'myType' is a variable but is used like a type.

Our ultimate goal is to be able to get JSON data and turn it into the appropriate class dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var myType = Type.GetType(typeName);
var template = typeof(OutgoingEnvelope<>);
var typeToSet = template.MakeGenericType(myType);

var fromJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutgoingEnvelope<typeToSet>>(jsonData);
```

it should work.

Comment: This can/will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a generic in that way the type must be known at compile time. It would be similar if you tried to create a new instance of myType using `var instance = new myType();`, this would also not compile for the same reason (more or less).

The deserializer on JsonConvert (see [DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm)) offers a non generic version that you could then cast later if you wanted to. This has some requirements though.

- You have to define an interface for your container and optionally the generic type parameter
- The generic interface parameter must be marked as covariant (out keyword)

This is a self contained example that executes, the only thing missing is getting the `Type` from a string instead of hard coded.

```
public class SomeController {
    public void Write()
    {   
        var objectToSerialize = new OutgoingEnvelope<SomeDocument>()    
        {   
            Documents = new List<SomeDocument>() {new SomeDocument() {Name = "Hi"}},    
            TypeId = "Some type"    
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

        // var myType = Type.GetType(typeName); 
        var myType = typeof(OutgoingEnvelope<SomeDocument>);    
        var fromJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, myType) as IOutgoingEnvelope<IDocumentType>;   

        if(fromJsonString == null)  
            throw new NullReferenceException(); 
    }   
}

public interface IDocumentType
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    // known common members in the interface
}

public class SomeDocument : IDocumentType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IOutgoingEnvelope<T> where T : IDocumentType
{
    string TypeId { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<T> Documents { get; }
}

public class OutgoingEnvelope<T> : IOutgoingEnvelope<T> where T : IDocumentType
{
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    public OutgoingEnvelope()
    {
        Documents = new List<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Documents { get; set; }
}
```